# What sort of exceptions should I be throwing from inside Kohana 3?

Tags: php, exception, kohana, kohana-3

I've seen the code examples on [this article](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc/), but throwing `Controller_Exception_404` produces an error.

I've just been throwing plain exceptions. I remember in Kohana 2.3 there were different ones you could throw, depending on the situation.

Does anyone have a list of what exceptions should be thrown when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the exception you want is `Kohana_Request_Exception`. Here's a list of all the exceptions Kohana defines (generated using `grep -iR "class .*Exception" .`):

```
class Validate_Exception extends Kohana_Validate_Exception {}
class Kohana_Validate_Exception extends Kohana_Exception {
class Kohana_Request_Exception extends Kohana_Exception {  }
class Kohana_Exception extends Exception {
class Kohana_View_Exception extends Kohana_Exception {  }
```

If you want a 404 response code, I think you'll also have to do this in your controller

```
$this->request->status = 404;
```

I don't know what the "official" best practice is, but this is what I've found by playing around.